# How to emulate this design in CSS? (grid-like)

Tags: html, css, grid, outline

I designed the following using a bit of a cheat, margins and outlines.

Website is live at http://davidafroivey.github.io

[image]

Working CSS is

```
body { margin: auto; max-width: 736px }

span.imgs { display: block; font-size: 0px; margin: 2px }

img { outline: 2px solid white }

img.a { width: 36% }
img.b { width: 64% }
```

Full source code is available here http://github.com/davidafroivey/davidafroivey.github.io/blob/master/index.html

**How can I achieve a similar aesthetic without outlines?** I want to be able to build in shadows which  doesn't work with outlines because outlines obstruct what's behind them.

What often happens is I add padding or margins to a span and it breaks the grid design. This is the best I can muster right now.

Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

Answer (score 0):

```css
.a,
.b {
  padding:10px;display:inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;float:left
}
.imgs a:nth-child(odd):after{clear:both;display:block;content:''}
.a {
  width:30%
}
.b {
  width:70%}
.a img,
.b img {
  width:100%;box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px black;
}
```

```html
<span class="imgs">

           <a href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/a/1.jpg" class="a">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/a/1.jpg"></a>

           <a class="b" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/b/1.jpg">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/b/1.jpg"></a>

           <a class="b" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/b/2.jpg">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/b/2.jpg"></a>

           <a class="a" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/a/2.jpg">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/a/2.jpg"></a>

           <a class="a" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/a/3.jpg">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/a/3.jpg"></a>

           <a class="b" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/b/3.jpg">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/b/3.jpg"></a>

           <a class="b" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/b/4.jpg">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/b/4.jpg"></a>

           <a class="a" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/a/4.jpg">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/a/4.jpg"></a>

           <a class="a" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/a/5.jpg">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/a/5.jpg"></a>

           <a class="b" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/b/5.jpg">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/b/5.jpg"></a>

           <a class="b" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/b/6.jpg">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/b/6.jpg"></a>

           <a class="a" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/a/6.jpg">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/a/6.jpg"></a>

           <a class="a" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/a/7.jpg">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/a/7.jpg"></a>

           <a class="b" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/b/7.jpg">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/b/7.jpg"></a>

           <a class="b" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/b/8.jpg">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/b/8.jpg"></a>

           <a class="a" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/a/8.jpg">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidafroivey/david-paint/master/a/8.jpg"></a>

</span>
```

You can use `padding:1px;box-sizing:border-box` ( remove `outline` )

Comment: On `img` or `span.imgs`? Thanks.

Comment: On `img`, you most replace `padding:1px;box-sizing:border-box` with `outline:2px solid #fff` property

Comment: I tried `img { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 10px; box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px black }` and I get this http://s31.postimg.org/pk8o2s7bd/Screen_Shot_2016_07_10_at_1_36_22_PM.png –  how do I shrink the images and have shadows right behind them? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! But what about the smaller paintings being shorter than the wider ones?

Comment: Did you use the values `36%` and `63%` intentionally so it wouldn't break the design?

Comment: With this solution you can change values and it not break ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116978/discussion-between-morteza-senfi-and-zaydek).